# Sometimes I get syntax error for no apparent reason, sometimes this only fixes itself after restarting the program

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

This is a piece of my code:

```
RandomNumber2 = round(random.uniform(0,1),0) 
NegativeOrNot_n2 = NegativeOrNotList[int(RandomNumber2)] 

n1 = round((random.uniform(nmin, nmax)*float(NegativeOrNot_n1)),1)
n2 = round((random.uniform(sqrt(n1),10*sqrt(n1)),1)
answer = (round(n2/n1), 2))
print("Guess", n2,"divided by", n1)
```

---

And it randomly tells me there is a syntax error when I define the answer:

```
answer = (round(n2/n1), 2))
^
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

@David
You have mismatched ')' parenthesis in code. This is the right parenthesis match both these lines.

```
n2 = round((random.uniform(sqrt(n1),10*sqrt(n1)),1))
answer = (round(n2/n1), 2)
```